# Permutation and Combination...

Tags: permutations, combinations

Suppose there are N numbers (N is a set of natural numbers), say {1,3,6,9,10,45,60}. Now i know there are total nC2 ways to choose 2 numbers from it. But i want to know sum of difference of all this numbers. It can be done on paper for smaller number. But for larger N (10^6) is there any formula to compute this.

Comment: What does 'the sum of difference of all this numbers" mean?  Take a smaller set, say $\{1,2,4\}$.  What is the sum of difference of that?

Comment: All possible ways are {1,2}, {1,4}, {2,4}  => diff = (2 - 1) + (4 - 1) + (4 - 2).

Answer (score 0):

The combinations of pairs between $n$ numbers is ${n \choose 2}$, but it actually computed as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i}x_i-x_j=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i}x_j=S_n-\sum_{i=1}^{n}S_i$, with $S_i$ the sum of $i$ terms.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician. So, can you provide a smaller example. Because i don't understand last part.